# Custom Combobox with values

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox, custom-controls

I have a windows application with multiple Forms containing the same ComboBoxes.
These Comboboxes have fixed items. On each Form I load the Comboboxes with these values.
For example:

```
Public Sub New()
   InitializeComponent()
   With Combobox1.Items
         .Insert(0, "Value1")
         .Insert(1, "Value2")
         .Insert(2, "Value3")
   End With
   With Combobox2.Items
         .Insert(0, "Value4")
         .Insert(1, "Value5")
         .Insert(2, "Value6")
   End With
End Sub
```

I don't want to repeat this code on every Form so, is there a way to create a custom Combobox that is pre-filled with these values, and then inherit the Comboboxes on each Form? Or is there another proper solution?

**UPDATE 1**
Based on jmcilhinney's comment, I have created this class

```
 Public Class ComboClass
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Sub New(ByVal sender As String)
        If sender = "R" Then
            With Items
                    .Insert(0, "Value1")
                    .Insert(1, "Value2")
                    .Insert(2, "Value3")
            End With
        Else
                With Items
                    .Insert(0, "Value4")
                    .Insert(1, "Value5")
                    .Insert(2, "Value6")
                End With
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then I added the new custom control to my Form.
In the Private Sub InitializeComponent() method designer code, I have the following:

```
Me.Combobox1 = New MyApplication.ComboClass("R")
Me.Combobox2 = New MyApplication.ComboClass("A")
```

I get the following designer error:

```
The variable 'Combobox1' is either undeclared or was never assigned. 
The variable 'Combobox2' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are multiple solutions. For one, you can do as you suggested. Simply add a new class to your project, inherit the `ComboBox` class, add a constructor that calls the base constructor and then adds the items. You could also write a method in a module or elsewhere that takes two `ComboBoxes` as arguments and populates them, then call that method from each form. Alternatively, if the controls are completely the same on all forms, create a base form class with the `ComboBoxes` and then inherit that form in all your others.

Comment: Thanks. I have made some changes but still not working. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Where have you defined those objects, `Combobox1` and `Combobox2`? Do you have, somewhere, `Private ComboBox1 As ComboClass = Nothing`?

Comment: The changes you made aren't really going to help anyway. If you are adding two `ComboClass` controls to your form in the designer then they are the controls on your form. Assigning two different controls to those fields (even if they exist) doesn't mean that those two new controls are magically added to your form. The two original controls will still be displayed on the form and the ones you create in code will not be displayed at all. If you want to call a constructor with parameters then don't use the designer at all and add the controls to the form in code.

Comment: I'm adding them by dragging the new controls from the tool box.
The code I shared is working fine and the values are loaded perfectly but when I view the designer, the error appears and I cant see the controls. If I'm going to do everything in the form itself, then what is the point of customizing the control? I want to avoid creating the same control and loading the same values on every form. How can I do it? I'm sorry but I didn't understand this "Assigning two different controls to those fields (even if they exist) doesn't mean that those two new controls are magically added to your form"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the class Constructor (which isn't much useful if you want to create your controls in the Designer), you could add a Public Property that accepts an Enumerator (or even a String value, as you're doing here) that lets you define, at Design Time, pre-defined data sets when the property value is changed.

As a note, avoid tampering with the Designer.vb code. It's handled by the Form Designer, you don't usually write anything here: it will be delete as soon as  the Form design is modified.

The custom Property is called **`CustomDataSet`**, here.
The code here also drops down the ComboBox List, so you can see what has been set.

This is how it works:

[image: Custom ComboBox Selector]

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

<DesignerCategory("Code")>
Public Class ComboClass
    Inherits ComboBox

    Private Selector As DataSelector = DataSelector.None

    Public Enum DataSelector
        None = 0
        Set1
        Set2
    End Enum

    Public Sub New()
        ' Initialization code, if needed
    End Sub

    <DefaultValue(DataSelector.None)>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
    Public Property CustomDataSet As DataSelector
        Get
            Return Selector
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataSelector)
            Selector = value
            Me.SetData()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub SetData()
        Me.Items.Clear()
        Select Case Me.Selector
            Case DataSelector.None
            Case DataSelector.Set1
                Me.Items.AddRange({"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"})
            Case DataSelector.Set2
                Me.Items.AddRange({"Value6", "Value7", "Value8"})
            Case Else
                'NOP
        End Select
        If DesignMode Then Me.DroppedDown = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. it just shows the combo flashing when I run the app and when loading the form.

Comment: Yep. Use the modified code. There was a mistake in the Designer Serialization setting: the wrong value (visible) *slipped in*, it should be `Hidden`, otherwise the values will be set twice :). Also, the ListControl of the ComboBox, if you want to use it, should only be droppen in design mode.